# Http Request with stream_context_create()

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to send a POST request using stream_context_create() function but I'm not getting the expected output.

Flow ( codes below ):

1. index.php - accepts input from a user via a form and submits it to submit.php.
2. submit.php - Accepts the POST request and displays suitable output.
3. upload.php - uses stream_context_create() to send a POST request to submit.php.

Codes:

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="submit.php">
            <input type="text"  name="field" />
            <button id="submit">Upload</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" />
        </form>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('submit')
                .addEventListener('click', function(){
                     document.querySelector('form').submit();
                }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  == 'POST'){
    echo "<input type='text' value='value = " . $_POST['field'] . "' />";
}
else {
    echo "form not submitted correctly";
}
?>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$url = 'submit.php';
$data = array('field' => 'Check1');
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$fp = fopen('submit.php', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Output received when loading upload.php**

```
"; } else { echo "form not submitted correctly"; } ?>
/*******************************************************/
```

I don't know what's going wrong ? Any other solutions for submitting a POST request are appericiated.

Comment: Firstly, you should correct your malformed HTML.

Comment: Secondly, the output you're showing us doesn't match the source code you have. Please post more code.

Comment: I have corrected the malformed HTML(at least according to me) but for the output, I have copied it as such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the url. Changing the url from submit.php to http://localhost/submit.php did the job as shown below:

`$fp = fopen('submit.php', 'r', false, $context);`

to

`$fp = fopen('http://localhost/submit.php', 'r', false, $context);`

Comment: Correct. Reading a *.php file from your hard disc does not automatically execute it as script. Processing it through an PHP-enabled web server does.